# Data from column are not projected

Tags: sql, postgresql

I work with the database which i downloaded two weeks ago from website "portgrepro.ru" This db includes a lot of tables. One of these tables is "aircrafts", which consists of three columns:aircraft_code, model and range. I performed a command "select" but, unfortunately, data from column "model" were not projected. Well, i don't understand the reason of this error. Firstly,this table has names.I have unzipped database using a texteditor and found names of these models. Secondly,i have both of keyboards: my local (russian keyboard) and an english keyboard. Some people said me that the problem is locales. Well, i don't think so, as if this problem is locales i will have strange symbols in column "model" like this №$####%##$ but symbols are not in this column. Please help me. If i do some stupid things or don't understand simple rules do not blame me( I am just dummy

[image]

Comment: Are you sure there are any data? Column also can contain NULL values.

Comment: I am sure that column has data. As i said, i opened this db in the texeditor and found these data.